# I need help locating missing javascript for bootstrap component

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the javascript found here https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/gallery/ (especially the Gallery with image filtering, and the Lightbox gallery with gutters + zoom pop-up component). However the js code snippet does not include all the js. I downloaded the zip file with all the js for all the examples shown however it's too many files. There must be a way to just find the js files needed for those two components. Does anyone have any suggestions?

As is with just the html and js code snippets, the filtering does not work. Also for the lightbox component, as is the pop-up/zoom window icons do not show either. Any help is appreciated as I'm trying to use for my portfolio and need to post once I fix it.

Thank you for any help or suggestions! - Okay I guess this won't work without the Pro Version (thank you crimson589).

Now I'm trying to use this code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp but in two different sections on the page so I changed the variables in the script to:

```html
<script>

    filterSelection("all1")
    function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv1");
   if (c == "all1") c = "";
   // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and         remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
    }

    // Show filtered elements
    function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
     arr2 = name.split(" ");
     for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
     if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
     }
    }
    }

    // Hide elements that are not selected
    function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    // Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer1");
    var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    });
    }
    </script>

    <script>

    filterSelection("all2")
    function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv2");
    if (c == "all2") c = "";
    // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and      remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
    }

    // Show filtered elements
    function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
    }
    }

    // Hide elements that are not selected
    function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

    // Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
    var btnContainer2 = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer2");
    var btns = btnContainer2.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
     });
     }
    </script>



  
    <style>
    .container {
     /* overflow: hidden;  */
     }

    .filterDiv1,.filterDiv2 {
     color: #ffffff;
     text-align: center;
     display: none; /* Hidden by default */
      }

    /* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
    .show {
     display: block;
     }

     /* Style the buttons */
     .btn {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     cursor: pointer;
     }

     /* Add a light grey background on mouse-over */
     .btn:hover {
     background-color: #ddd;
     }

     /* Add a dark background to the active button */
    .btn.active {
     background-color: #666;
     color: white;
     }

    </style>
```

It's not working though even though I changed the class names in my two different sections to filter different content in two blocks. The all1 and all2 tabs aren't showing by default either.

Comment: It says it's a "PRO COMPONENT" did you pay for the theme?

Comment: @crimson589 Hmm... there is a free download (zip folder)... maybe you're right... it's confusing though...

Comment: Well, yeah there's a free download, that doesn't include the component you're looking for.

Comment: @crimson589 Okay I see, thank you! ... how about if I use this code here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp I want to use the filter in two different sections however it's not working the way I'm doing it...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `jquery`, you can use jquery solution. This is a quick solution that works with the HTML that they have on that example page. I don't work with various CMS solutions, so you will need to determine the best place for the code.

The javascript is the only code that you need to copy, the rest is for demonstration purposes.

```js
$(document).on("click",".filter",function(){
    var target = $(this).data("rel");
    $(".pics").hide();
    $(".pics." + target).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.gallery {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-width: 33%;
-moz-column-width: 33%;
column-width: 33%; }
.gallery .pics {
-webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
transition: all 350ms ease; }
.gallery .animation {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1); }

@media (max-width: 450px) {
.gallery {
-webkit-column-count: 1;
-moz-column-count: 1;
column-count: 1;
-webkit-column-width: 100%;
-moz-column-width: 100%;
column-width: 100%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
.btn.filter {
padding-left: 1.1rem;
padding-right: 1.1rem;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Grid row -->
<div class="row">

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="1">Mountains</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-black waves-effect filter" data-rel="2">Sea</button>

  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

</div>
<!-- Grid row -->

<!-- Grid row -->
<div class="gallery" id="gallery">

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Vertical/mountain3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

</div>
<!-- Grid row -->
```